# Problemas con el cultureinfo en vb.net con el conector de mysql versión 8

Tags: mysql, vb.net, mysqlconnector

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture=System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("es-DO")
System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.ShortDatePattern = "dd'/'MM'/'yyyy"
```

esta dos lineas de código se ejecutan el iniciar el sistema lo que hacen es que independientemente del formato de fecha que tenga la computadora el sistema manejará las fechas para convertirdas de date a string y viceversa, también en los select que se hacen al servidor.

hoy actualicé el conector de mysql de la versión 6.9.4 a la versión 8.0.31 y esto dejó de funcionar, ahora si hago un select a una fecha como en este codigo

```
   Public Function BFecha_Servidor() As Boolean
        Using conn = ConexionADO.ObtenerConeccion()
            conn.Open()
            Dim MysqlCommand As New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand("SELECT curdate()", conn)
            Fecha_Servidor = MysqlCommand.ExecuteScalar().ToString
        End Using
        Return True
    End Function
```

antes de la actualización me devolvía la fecha en string con formato dd/MM/yyyy ahora despues de la actualización me la devuelve en formato MM/dd/yyyy

a que se debe este cambio?
y como puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: por que, basicamente, como sabe el sistema que eso es una fecha??? antes te andaba no se porque.. pero eso, no deberia andar, si no lo casteas a una fecha..

Comment: luego cuando lo voy a utilizar lo casteo a fecha con CDate pero como el sistema está esperando el formato dd/MM/yyyy ahora me da error porque solo las fechas que obtengo de la base de datos me vienen con formato MM/dd/yyyy, las que obtengo de un datetimepicker si salen con formato correcto, y las puedo convertir a formato date sin ningún problema.

Comment: es que el problema es el conector, no todo lo otro que haces, que es correcto.. hace una transformacion al traer la info desde la db y listo...

Comment: eso yo lo se que el problema es el conector, pero lo que busco es una solucion de 5 minutos, porque la de varios meses ya me la se, lei por ahì que era que el conector 6.9.4 toma el formato regional del hilo principal de la aplicacion, y que el 8 toma el formato del servidor, pero probe cambiando el charset del servidor y el collation y aun asi me sigue dando la fecha en el mismo formato MM/dd/yyyy